# To “Er” Is Human

Tags: steganography, word-property

I’m back with another annoying word puzzle. The following are clues to a series of “er” words. They consist of pairs of words or phrases that are both associated with a particular word that ends in “er”. One association will generally depend on a trick or an unusual meaning. For example “Insect catcher/Parent” could clue “mother” since a mother is a parent and a “moth-er” catches moths which are, of course, insects.

Now, if I’m giving you two clues for every word and I’ve already told you they all end in “er” then it would be too easy unless there was a twist of some kind. And there is. Your answer must include a clue pair for the *secret* word.

Good luck.

> Nile/Petunia
>   Proposal/Killer
>   Ready for action/Amputator
>   Anesthetist/Pi
>   Euphemistic curser/Peril
>   Pitcher/Selective sheep minder
>   Submit/Ripper

**Addendum**

It was entirely by chance... er, that is, I planted by devilish cunning an Easter egg in this puzzle. The initial letters of the seven clues anagram to the word “snapper” which could be clued as “Fish/Card player”.

I amaze me.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Here are my answers -- I hope I'm the one who has discovered the puzzle creator's intended solutions.

> Flower (a river is a "flow-er", a thing that flows)
>  Offer (a killer is one who "offs" someone)
>  Unlimber (meaning "unpack" or "someone who unlimbs")
>  Number (an anesthetist is one who numbs)
>  Danger ("dang" is a minced oath for "damn", so a "dang-er" is a euphemistic curser)
>  Ewer (a "ewe-r" must be someone who only cares about *female* sheep)
>  Render (to "rend" is to tear apart)

And of course,

> the first sentence of my answer includes "one who has discovered" and "creator": a clue pair for FOUNDER, which can be seen by reading the first letter of each of the clued words.

Comment: Excellently done. For the clues I would of course also accepted “Fvax/Pnfgre bs zrgnyf”. Unexpectedly, I just discovered that I might have had to accept “Fish/Finger popper” as well. If it’s ok, I’ll wait a few minutes to see if someone gets the missing word. Congrats!

Comment: The missing word could be (rot13)Hayvzore.

Comment: @Ankoganit Ah, sounds right! That's a new one to me -- I'll add it in.

Comment: Grats again to you and @Ankoganit!